# Selenium Webdriver: Page factory initialization using paths relative to other elements?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, pageobjects

I'm trying to write a page object in Selenium Webdriver using the page factory `@FindBy` annotations. The page object is for a sidebar, and the parent WebElement containing all elements the page object needs to interact with is initialized in this way:

```
@FindBy (xpath = "//div[contains(@class,'yui3-accordion-panel-content') and child::div[.='Sidebar']]")
WebElement sidebar;
```

I then want the search input relative to this `sidebar` element. Is there a way to do this referencing `sidebar` element? I could copy and paste the entire path to the beginning:

```
@FindBy (xpath = "//div[contains(@class,'yui3-accordion-panel-content') and child::div[.='Sidebar']]//input[@id='search']")
```

But I'd much rather make it relative to the first element. Is anything like this possible?

```
@FindBy (parent = "sidebar", xpath = ".//input[@id='search']")
```

The [Selenium documentation on the @FindBy annotation](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/FindBy.html) is a bit lacking...

Comment: No, this is not possible with @FindBy.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer is to implement an ElementLocatorFactory that allows you to provide a search context (meaning, a driver or a WebElement).

```
public class SearchContextElementLocatorFactory
        implements ElementLocatorFactory {

    private final SearchContext context;

    public SearchContextElementLocatorFactory(SearchContext context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ElementLocator createLocator(Field field) {
        return new DefaultElementLocator(context, field);
    }
}
```

Then, when instantiating your page object, use this locator factory.

```
WebElement parent = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'yui3-accordion-panel-content') and child::div[.='Sidebar']]"));
SearchContextElementLocatorFactory elementLocatorFactory = new SearchContextElementLocatorFactory(parent);
PageFactory.initElements(elementLocatorFactory, this);
```

Now your `@FindBy` annotations will be relative to `parent`. For example, to get the main sidebar `WebElement`:

```
@FindBy(xpath = ".")
WebElement sideBar;
```

Comment: Thanks, very useful, but I wonder if there is a way to instantiate the page object without finding the parent element (just set the locator of the parent and instantiate when element are being looked up, which matches the pattern better, imo)?

Comment: The answer looks like a one-time configuration for all FindBys you have on a page. Is there any possibility to configure it for any single FindBy (like in the question >>@FindBy (parent = "sidebar", xpath = ".//input[@id='search']")<<)

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible this way. But you can use getter methods instead of annotation-based initialization:

```
public class SomePage {
    @FindBy (xpath = "//div[contains(@class,'yui3-accordion-panel-content') and   child::div[.='Sidebar']]")
    private WebElement sidebar;

    private WebElement getSomeChildElement() {
        return siderbar.findElement(By.id("somechild"));
    }
}
```

Comment: I figured. That's what I've been doing.