# Serenity BDD - how to implement a custom FindBy?

Tags: xpath, dojo, serenity-bdd

I am implementing Serenity BDD to build an automation suite for a product. I want to be able to find elements by xpaths which will be evaluated during run time.

For example, I want something like:

```
@FindBy(label="First Name")
private WebElementFacade firstNameTextBox;
```

Finding an element by label *'First Name'* will be the same as finding it by xpath

```
".//div[(contains(@class,'mdr_label mdr_caption') or contains(@class,'fieldItemLabel')) and contains(.,'First Name')]/following-sibling::div//input"
```

I don't want to really repeat this long xpath in every declaration. I use the Dojo framework and so I have no other locators to get these elements other than by xpaths.

So, how do I add a custom `FindBy` type?

Comment: Seems a solution would be extending most of `net.serenitybdd.core.annotations` classes/interfaces/enums and concatenating your xpath expression with whatever parameter you provide. Have you tried this?

Comment: The answer to your question is right here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24251739/selenium-webdriver-page-factory-initialization-using-paths-relative-to-other-el